# Get Index while iterating list with stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
List<Rate> rateList = 
       guestList.stream()
                .map(guest -> buildRate(ageRate, guestRate, guest))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());  

class Rate {
    protected int index;
    protected AgeRate ageRate;
    protected GuestRate guestRate;
    protected int age;
}
```

In the above code, is it possible to  pass index of `guestList` inside `buildRate` method. I need to pass index also while building `Rate` but could not manage to get index with `Stream`.

Comment: you will need to fold(or reduce in java8). it's very annoying that java 8 implements (so-called) functional programming without providing tuple.

Comment: @JasonHu Update: Java 16+ offers a nominal tuple, [`record`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395). A record can even be declared locally within a method as well as nested in another class or written separately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't provided the signature of `buildRate`, but I'm assuming you want the index of the elements of `guestList` to be passed in first (before `ageRate`).  You can use an `IntStream` to get indices rather than having to deal with the elements directly:

```
List<Rate> rateList = IntStream.range(0, guestList.size())
    .mapToObj(index -> buildRate(index, ageRate, guestRate, guestList.get(index)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is there `Instream. range(0, size). stream()` ?

Comment: `IntStream` is already a `Stream`, so there's no need to *re-stream* it.

Comment: There is one extra `.stream` in your code, please remove that. I will accept your answer

Comment: Oh whoops!  I originally copied your code and forgot to remove the call to `stream`.  My apologies.

Comment: To be nitpicking, `IntStream` is not already a `Stream`, but supports almost the same operations, as far as there are `int` specific specializations. For all other operations, you can call `boxed()` to truly have a `Stream`.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Guava in your classpath, the [`Streams.mapWithIndex`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#mapWithIndex-java.util.stream.Stream-com.google.common.collect.Streams.FunctionWithIndex-) method (available since version 21.0) is exactly what you need:

```
List<Rate> rateList = Streams.mapWithIndex(
        guestList.stream(),
        (guest, index) -> buildRate(index, ageRate, guestRate, guest))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```