# How can I get the index of item inside the Java streams?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-stream, indexof

I have a code which is as follows:

```
Arrays.stream(myArray).forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
```

Does streams in Java have any ability of getting the index of the current item that I can use them inside the lambda expression?

For example in JavaScript we have this kind of code which can give us the index:

```
myArray.forEach((index, item) => console.log(`${index} ${item}`));
```

Do we have any equivalent in Java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Index while iterating list with stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49080255/get-index-while-iterating-list-with-stream)

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a concise way to iterate over a stream with indices in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8)

Answer (score 2):

Yes to answer your question, in Java you can iterate over a stream with indices.

This is a very simple basic code  which shows how to get the index :

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] array = { "Goat", "Cat", "Dog", "Crow", "Snake" }; 
        
        IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                 .mapToObj(index -> String.format("%d -> %s", index, array[index]))
                 .forEach(System.out::println); 
                 
    }
    
}
```

Output :

```
0 -> Goat                                                                                                                                                  
1 -> Cat                                                                                                                                                   
2 -> Dog                                                                                                                                                   
3 -> Crow                                                                                                                                                  
4 -> Snake
```